# Is there a way to open a workspace from an extension in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing an extension that programmatically create a `*.code-workspace` file and I'd like to open it in the current window. Is there a way? Alternatively, it can open up a new window.

Answer (score 3):

How about `workspace.updateWorkspaceFolders(<start>,<deleteCount>,{uri: folderUriToAdd})` for opening the folder containing that `.workspace` file? This should preserve open files in Explorer.

Alternatively you could use `commands.executeCommand("vscode.openFolder",<uri>,<newWindow>)` and pass it the workspace uri, but this generates a new extension host process, either in your current window or a new one, depending on the value of newWindow.

Docs for those functions here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api and here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api-commands

Comment: You need to open file  in current workspace window only, otherwise you can't control the newly opened window from current running extension host.